# Setting this inside the functions Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the next code:

```js
const obj = {
    name:  'Hi',
    first: () => {
        return this
    },
    other: {
        name: 'last',
        sec: function() {
            this.c = '2'
            return function() {
                this.s = '3'
                return this; // expect {s:3}
            }
        }
    }
}


const t = obj.other.sec()
console.log(t())
```

In console.log i expect `{s:3}` but there is not that object. 
 Question: Why there is not `{s:3}`? Or `function()` should have its own context

Comment: returning console.log(t().s) showing "3" in console

Answer (score 1):

It's not there because `this` in JS is *dynamic* and depends on the *scope*.

1. Arrow functions *don't* have their own scope, so `obj.first()` will *not* return you `obj` but instead returns the *global context* (in a browser, usually `window`) or `undefined` when running in `strict mode`!
2. Functions via `function` *do* have a dedicated scope. However, when you call `obj.other.sec()`, the context of `this` in the `sec` function points to `obj.other`, not `obj`.
3. The function returned by `obj.other.sec()` does (or rather: *can*) create *a new scope*, since it's called *without* a context. But since it's also called without `new`, `this` points to the *global context* (see point 1).

Depending on what you want to achieve, the simplest solution is to replace `this` with the correct context. For example, if you want all function to run in the context of `obj`, just replace every `this` with `obj`:

```js
const obj = {
    name:  'Hi',
    first: () => {
        return obj;
    },
    other: {
        name: 'last',
        sec: function() {
            obj.c = '2'
            return function() {
                obj.s = '3'
                return obj;
            }
        }
    }
}


const t = obj.other.sec()
console.log(t()) // <-- now logs `obj` with a `c` and an `s` property added
```

Or maybe you want varying context's:

```js
const obj = {
    name:  'Hi',
    first: () => {
        return obj;
    },
    other: {
        name: 'last',
        sec: function() {
            obj.other.c = '2'
            return function() {
                obj.other.s = '3'
                return obj.other;
            }
        }
    }
}


const t = obj.other.sec()
console.log(t()) // <-- now logs `obj.other` with a `c` and an `s` property added
```

And in case `obj.other.sec()` should return a *new* object that is not related to `obj` or `obj.other`, then... well... just *return a new object*:

```js
const obj = {
    name:  'Hi',
    first: () => {
        return obj;
    },
    other: {
        name: 'last',
        sec: function() {
            obj.other.c = '2'
            return function() {
                return { s: 3 };
            }
        }
    }
}


const t = obj.other.sec()
console.log(t()) // <-- now logs a new object with an `s` property
```

You can read more about the dynamic nature of `this` on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Comment: a question regarding `obj.other.sec()()`, why in this case i get undefined? In this case `sec` has a returned function, but why it is undefined, should't it use this context `this.c = '2'`?